# No type named iterator_category in std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

This code is giving an error :

```
vector<vector<bool> > revealed(vector<bool>(10, false), vector<bool>(10,false));
```

I am trying to define a 2D boolean array that has all elements as false by default.

The error is

```
.\stl_iterator_base_types.h|165|error: no type named 'iterator_category' in 'class std::vector<bool>'|
```

The error refers to *line 165* of **stl_iterator_base_types.h**

```
162 template<typename _Iterator>
163 struct iterator_traits
164 {
165     typedef typename _Iterator::iterator_category iterator_category;
166     typedef typename _Iterator::value_type        value_type;
167     typedef typename _Iterator::difference_type   difference_type;
168     typedef typename _Iterator::pointer           pointer;
169     typedef typename _Iterator::reference         reference;
170 };
```

By the way, I am using Code::Blocks(with MinGW) as my IDE

Comment: What are you expecting the code to achieve?

Comment: A 2D array of boolean elements, of size 10x10, with all 100 elements set to _false_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would initialize such a vector as follows

```
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> revealed(10, std::vector<bool>(10, false));
```

The reason is that the constructor overload you are trying to use for `std::vector` is

```
vector(size_type count, const T& value);
```

So you can see the first argument is the count, the second is the value. By this notion, you want the outer vector to be

```
vector(10, "vectors_of_length_10_wlth_all_false_values")
           ^
```

The way you signify the second argument is

```
std::vector<bool>(10, false)
```

The first argument for the outer vector is simply `10` because you want it to contain 10 of these vectors that have 10 `false` values.